# Jquery hide/show delay

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 blocks in the same place where people can put in a number, if there is no number it hides.

But I want to give them the time to change it to another number. So I delay the hiding with ms. But then they see an animation of the hiding/showing.

```
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
  if($('#FenceMeters').val() != "" && Number($('#FenceMeters').val()) >=5){
     $('#testje').show();
     $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
  } else{
    $('#testje').hide(1000);
    $('#SummaryHTML').show();
  }
});
```

Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Can you give us the HTML please ?

Comment: We need you HTML to help you, please

Comment: you might want to add your html if the answer i posted isn't your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this if you want to delay the hide()

```
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
  if($('#FenceMeters').val() != "" && Number($('#FenceMeters').val()) >=5){
     $('#testje').show();
     $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
  } else{
    $('#testje').delay(5000).hide(1000); // delays hide with 5000 milliseconds
    $('#SummaryHTML').show();
  }
});
```